# Parse Json from API to Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, send

I have attached API on my javascript which has this result when I posted via postman:

```
{"result": {
    "clientId": 1,
    "session": "yJZdWRhIjoiSEExMDA4MzAyMCJ9.wrBz8JpNqMZlqv8Pz2Tx1x-XYecfdsH2B5uTbNPfiQE",
    "client name": Andrew,
    "address": [
      ["1","Bandung","West Java","Indonesia"],
      ["2","Depok","West Java","Indonesia"]
  }
}
```

and here's the API script:

```
var content='';
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:
rest_url+
'update/yJZdWRhIjoiSEExMDA4MzAyMCJ9.wrBz8JpNqMZlqv8Pz2Tx1x-XYecfdsH2B5uTbNPfiQE/'+_ClientId,
success: function (data) {
_Client  = data;

}
});
```

How could I add the content of json result to fill this empty var?

```
var address = ?????
var client_name = ?????
```

Comment: jQuery already decodes the JSON response into a regular JavaScript object. Just read it as in any other object.

Comment: Yes, so add it to the options: type: "POST", dataType: "JSON", url: ...

Comment: `var address = data.result.address; var client_name = data.result.client_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         ....
         ....
         dataType: 'json', // don't forget !!!
         success: function(data) {
                      var address = data.result.address;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is works for me. Also the developer said that it may use jsonp since cross origin request. Should I do something else?

Comment: JSONP is an extension of JSON to get rid of cross-domain restrictions. You'll have to load script as JSON + a callback function. But unfortunately, I'm far for being an expert of JSONP. I advice you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about